# Python how to replace backslash with re.sub()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following string

```
mystr1 = 'mydirname'
myfile = 'mydirname\myfilename'
```

I'm trying to do this

```
newstr = re.sub(mystr1 + "\","",myfile)
```

How do I escape the backslash I'm trying to concatenate to mystr1?

Comment: I am aware that this does in no way answer your question, but if possible don't even go there; use `os.path.join` and other `os.path` functions to manipulate paths in system-independent manner.

Comment: @Amadan, thanks for you answer, but I'm not trying to manipulate any paths, I'm just trying to take content from a specific file (for that, I'm using os.path) and then I am minifying the data and placing it as a JS var according to the original filename. I'm just manipulating the string of the filename (which includes the full path) for the JS var.

Comment: I just thought that what you're doing is almost the same as `os.path.basename(myfile)`. My bad.

Comment: As an aside, be careful about using a single backslash in a string like that; see [DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence - what to use instead of \d?](/q/50504500).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need a quadruple backslash:

```
newstr = re.sub(mystr1 + "\\\\", "", myfile)
```

Reason:

- Regex to match a single backslash: `\\`
- String to describe this regex: `"\\\\"`.

Or you can use a raw string, so you only need a double backslash: `r"\\"`

Comment: you could also do `newstr = re.sub(mystr1 + re.escape("\\"), "", myfile)`.  If your slash is in its own variable `slash = "\\"`, you can `re.sub(mystr1 + re.escape(slash), "", myfile)`

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression, you can escape a backslash just like any other character by putting a backslash in front of it.  This means "\\" is a single backslash.

Comment: Yes, but we're dealing with strings here that *contain* a regular expression. Double escaping rules apply.

Comment: and although you might think that r"\" would get you the same as "\\", as r"\\" is "\\\\", you'd be wrong...you can't have a single \ :P