# Python regex to replace double backslash with single backslash

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace all double backslashes with just a single backslash. I want to replace `'class=\\"highlight'` with `'class=\"highlight'`. I thought that python treats `'\\'` as one backslash and `r'\\+'` as a string with two backslashes. But when I try

```
In [5]: re.sub(r'\\+', '\\', string)
sre_constants.error: bogus escape (end of line)
```

So I tried switching the replace string with a raw string:

```
In [6]: re.sub(r'\\+', r'\\', string)
Out [6]: 'class=\\"highlight'
```

Which isn't what I need. So I tried only one backslash in the raw string:

```
In [7]: re.sub(r'\\+', r'\', string)
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: Does this other [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10585406/1167750) help?  *(double escaping?)*

Comment: What does `string` look like?

Comment: string = 'class=\\"highlight'

Comment: @summea sorry this doesn't help: re.sub('\\\\', '\\', string) just gives me 'adfd\\"adfadf' and re.sub('\\\\', '\', string) gives me an EOL SyntaxError

Comment: @summea no, that actually looks like a duplicate answer as the last one you posted

Comment: @mill Actually I just edited the comment to show the answer first... but, it looks like [this issue](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash) goes further than I previously thought.  Inbar Rose has a nice alternative... although if you are working with path names in Windows (or something,) you may want to look into using [a different approach](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/).

Comment: The desired result `'class=\"highlight'` **doesn't make any sense**. There is no `\"` escape sequence. If you want the string to contain an actual backslash, then it will show `\\` when you display the *representation of* the string, but it only contains one backslash.

Comment: Which is to say: the displayed output - `Out [6]: 'class=\\"highlight'` - **is** the result you want. This string has **one** backslash in it, which is being **represented** as two. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

why not use `string.replace()`?

```
>>> s = 'some \\\\ doubles'
>>> print s
some \\ doubles
>>> print s.replace('\\\\', '\\')
some \ doubles
```

Or with "raw" strings:

```
>>> s = r'some \\ doubles'
>>> print s
some \\ doubles
>>> print s.replace('\\\\', '\\')
some \ doubles
```

Since the escape character is complicated, you still need to escape it so it does not escape the `'`

Comment: This works with the print, but not without it. 
print s.replace('\\\\', '\\')
=> some \ doubles
. But s.replace('\\\\', '\\')
=> some \\ doubles

Comment: `string.replace()` returns the object, you would have to to `s = s.replace()`

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. original_string = 'class=\\"highlight'; new_string = original_string.replace('\\\\', '\\'); new_string => 'class=\\"highlight'. The print statement removes the double backslash, not the replace. In fact, just doing print original_string => 'class=\"highlight', as well as print new_string => 'class=\"highlight'. You can also confirm this with new_string == original_string => True

Comment: @mill Wouldn't you still need the backslash to be escaped in the actual string/variable? :)  Otherwise... how would it know you wanted a backslash left in the final string/variable result...?

Comment: How did this get a checkmark if it doesn't work. @mill is correct in saying it only works with the print. Still can't find simple solution to this other than maybe analyzing each byte programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You only got one backslash in string:

```
>>> string = 'class=\\"highlight' 
>>> print string
class=\"highlight
```

Now lets put another one in there

```
>>> string = 'class=\\\\"highlight' 
>>> print string
class=\\"highlight
```

and then remove it again

```
>>> print re.sub('\\\\\\\\', r'\\', string)
class=\"highlight
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use .replace() twice!

I had the following path: `C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\PMI APP GIT\\pmi-app\\niton x5 test data`

To convert \ to single backslashes, i just did the following:

```
path_to_file = path_to_file.replace('\\','*')
path_to_file = path_to_file.replace('**', '\\')
```

first operation creates ** for every \ and second operation escapes the first slash, replacing ** with a single `\`.

Result:

```
C:**Users**z0044wmy**Desktop**PMI APP GIT**pmi-app**GENERATED_REPORTS
C:\Users\z0044wmy\Desktop\PMI APP GIT\pmi-app\GENERATED_REPORTS
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that this might be the simplest answer:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

The above outputs a path with \ (2 back slashes)

BUT if you wrap it with a print function, i.e.,
`print(os.getcwd())`
it will output the 2 slashes with 1 slash so you can then copy and paste into an address bar!