# Trailing slash in re.sub

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Path looks like:

```
CLOUD_PATH = os.path.join(HOME, 'library', 'data') 
WORKDIR = os.getcwd()
```

Then in script I have a function:

```
def urlchanger(src, dst):                                                                

    xmlsdir = os.path.join(src, 'Plugins', '_xmls', '')                                  

    xmlfiles = [ f for f in os.listdir(xmlsdir) if re.match(r'^.*\.xml', f)]             

    for file in xmlfiles:                                                                

        with open(os.path.join(xmlsdir, file), 'r+') as f:                               
            indata = f.read()                                                                                                                 

            if ('dontchange.me' in indata):                                              
                outdata = re.sub(r'http://dontchange.me/', dst, indata)                  
                print 'Updating file %s:\n \n%s' % (os.path.join(xmlsdir, file), outdata)                                            

                with open((os.path.join(os.environ['TEMP'], file)), 'w') as n:           
                    n.write(outdata)
```

Which called with:

```
urlchanger(WORKDIR, CLOUD_PATH)
```

Problem is, that `re.sub` performs substitution without trailing slash after `data` directory (result from out-file):

```
plugin assemblyUrl="C:\library\dataSomefile.dll"
```

Between `data` and `Somefile` - `dataSomefile`.

I tried add `''` to `CLOUD_PATH` like:

```
CLOUD_PATH = os.path.join(HOME, 'library', 'data', '')
```

But got an error:

```
...
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bogus escape (end of line)
```

And same for few other attempts...

P.S. Script reads data from source file, looks for `dontchange.me`, replaces it with given URL, and will write new new file. Python 2.7.

Comment: `if ('dontchange.me' in c for c in indata)` does not do what you want. It creates a generator and then tests the boolean value of that, which is _always true_. Did you mean `if any(the same generator expression)`? Also, it seems `indata` is a string, so `c` would be a character, so that expression does not make much sense in the first place...

Comment: I think `dst` is also sort-of treated as a regex, so if you are on windows and you have path separators like \ in there, they will be interpreted in the regex. You could pass a callable instead, just returning the `dst`. Please show a more complete code example, though!

Comment: @tobias_k yep, you are right :-) `in c for c in indata` left from previous coding (I tried `readlines` first, which return `list`). Thanks for note.

Comment: @tobias_k added full function and it's call with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution here: [Python how to replace backslash with re.sub()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585349/python-how-to-replace-backslash-with-re-sub)

So, result it:

```
if ('dontchange.me' in indata):                                        
    outdata = re.sub(r'http://dontchange.me/', dst + '\\\\', indata)
```

But any other tips/advise appreciated.

Comment: use r'\\' - then you don't need to escape characters

Comment: @M4ks `dst` is variable, passed in argument - is it possible use it as raw string here?