# Python regexp and raw string

Tags: python, regex, string

I typed the following line in Python shell:

```
In [67]: print(re.match(r"\d", "\\ddfss")) 

None
```

Since "\d" is a raw string, I expect that re.match will return a match object for the string "\ddfss". Do you know why it doesn't happen?

Comment: `\d` matches a *digit*. [To match ``\``, you need to double the ``\`` - ``r'\\d'``.](https://ideone.com/4LoeLh)

Comment: And here is a more proper  original: [*Python how to replace backslash with re.sub()*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585349/python-how-to-replace-backslash-with-re-sub)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, r"<expression>" mean string literals, meaning that the expression actually means a character of '\' and a character of 'n'

Comment: @CrazySyntax: Exactly, a literal ``\`` and a literal `n`. And a literal `\d` is a digit regex pattern. When you define regex patterns, use raw string literals - it is a common advice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew . OK... So, how can you explain this exaple? 
In [106]: print(re.match(r"\d", "o6fss"))
None

"\d" is supposed to look for a digit. You have a digit in the string "o6fss", and it still finds no match.

Comment: You have asked another dupe, see the link there. You miss up on understanding the difference between `re.match` and `re.search`. Too many identical questions have been asked, and keep on being asked :(