# Unexpected output with python `normpath`

Tags: python

I am trying to convert Windows file path to Unix using `os.path.normpath`. I am getting unexpected characters in file path.

```
import os
path1 = 'C:\Users\abcd\dir1'
path2 = os.path.normpath(path1)
path2
```

I want to replace "\" by "/". But output is  `'C:\\Users\x07bcd\\dir1'`. I am wondering how x07` comes in the picture and how to get rid of it.

Alternatively, I tried regex to replace "\" by "/".

Desired output is: `'C:/Users/abcd/dir1'`

I tried using answer of [Python how to replace backslash with re.sub()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585349/python-how-to-replace-backslash-with-re-sub) but could not get it to work. 
If I want to use it, can someone suggest how to do it?

`path3 = re.sub(path1 +"\\" "//")`

But there is error. I am new to python, so could not figure out proper syntax.

Comment: Use a raw string `r'C:\Users\abcd\dir1'`. Otherwise, `\a` gets treated as the sequence for the BEL character, `\x07` == Ctrl-G.

Comment: Don't use regex for this. When handling paths use functions that are built to do that job, like the `os.path` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw string or double slash in this case :

```
path1 = 'C:\\Users\\abcd\dir1'
```

or

```
path1 = r'C:\Users\abcd\dir1'
```

Comment: Added to original question. Can you comment how to use `re.sub` to replace slash? Thanks

Comment: @sarf34 what are you attempting to do with re sub? add the expected result in the question please

Comment: Added to question