# replace function to remove "\" in text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hello i hope someone  can help me with this issue
so i trying to scrapp iframe tag in a web page but i get some backslashes which i want to remove

i select the element

```
video=soup_product.select_one("div.col-lg-6:nth-of-type(3)>iframe")
```

and this is printing result :

```
<iframe allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"170\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/JwG10b9HtZQ\" width=\"305\"></iframe>
```

i tried too replace the backslash with replace function

```
str(video).replace('\', '')
```

but it show error

File "", line 2
videoiframe = str(video).replace("", "")
^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: _but it show error on syntax_ Show us the error.  Otherwise we can only guess what it is.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the error i updated the question

Comment: You need one more backslash.  `str(video).replace('\\', '')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585349/python-how-to-replace-backslash-with-re-sub

Answer (score 0):

Escape the backslash as well

```py
str(video).replace('\\', '')
```